# How do I collect Data URI content using dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone but I only want to use it's thumbnail generation ability and UI. I want to be able to collect all the data URIs and send them to the server in an HTTP request myself. How do I accomplish it ?

The documentation says, I can pass afucntion to url and it will get a custom file object but this object isn't the HTML5 File object which I can pass to FileReader and read it's content.

I know DropZone is using FileReader underneath for thumbnail generation but then it is directly using up that data. Is there a way I can get access to each data uri everytime I select a new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dropzone's `thumbnail` event, which is triggered when the thumbnail is generated for a file. It receives data uri as a second argument.

```
myDropzone.on('thumbnail', function(file, dataUri) {
    // use dataUri here
});
```

Documentation reference here : http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-thumbnail